# iOS 4.1 black screen before playing video using MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

My application flow is something like the following

1. A Video plays.
2. Once its done. Couple of icons are shown on the screen for users to tap on.
3. Depending on which icon was tapped, another video starts.
4. If no icon is tapped for like 5 seconds we automatically go to next video.

The problem is with 3. Just before the video starts a black screen appears for like 0.5 second.

Not sure what's going on because the videos in step 1 and step 4 plays fine.

It will be great if someone can give ideas to debug and fix this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put a background-image onto the player with:

```
[[moviePlayer view] setBackgroundColor:<UIImage>image];
```

Comment: How are you passing a UIImage to background color which requires parameter of type UIColor???